# Java Threads and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, chat

I have a threaded chat server application which requires MySQL authencation.

Is the best way to have 1 class create the MySQL connection, keep that connection open and let every thread use that connection but use own Query handler?

Or is it better to have all threads make a seperate connection to MySQL to authencate?

Or is it better to let 1 class handle the queries AND connections?

We are looking at a chatserver that should be able to handle upto 10.000 connections/users.

---

I am now using c3p0, and I created this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws PropertyVetoException
{
    ComboPooledDataSource pool = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    pool.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    pool.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db");
    pool.setUser("root");
    pool.setPassword("pw");
    pool.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    pool.setMinPoolSize(10);

    Database database = new Database(pool);
    try
    {

        ResultSet rs = database.query("SELECT * FROM `users`");

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("userid"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("username"));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        database.close();
    }
```

}

public class Database {

```
ComboPooledDataSource pool;
Connection conn;
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement st = null;

public Database (ComboPooledDataSource p_pool)
{
    pool = p_pool;
}

public ResultSet query (String _query)
{
    try {
        conn = pool.getConnection();
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(_query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return rs;
}

public void close ()
{
    try {
        st.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Would this be thread safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at connection pooling ? Check out (for example) [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) or [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html).

Briefly, connection pooling means that a pool of authenticated connections are used, and free connections are passed to you on request. You can configure the number of connections as appropriate. When you close a connection, it's actually returned to the pool and made available for another client. It makes life relatively easy in your scenario, since the pool looks after the authentication and connection management.

Comment: Thank's I will certainly look into this, that looks like the right solution.

Comment: DBCP is singlethreaded. He was explicitly asking for connecting in a multithreaded context. I would rather go for c3p0.

Comment: I'm not sure I see anything in DBCP to indicate that you can't use it in a multithreaded context. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Ps. the DBCP was meant as an example, not a recommendation *per se*. But it certainly didn't read correctly, so I've edited appropriately.

Comment: You can use it in multithreaded context, but the connection pool itself is synchronized and thus not really optimal for performance in multithreaded context.

Answer (score 2):

[c3p0 connection pool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) is a robust solution. You can also check dbcp but c3p0 shows better performance, supports auto-reconnection and some other features.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have just one connection.  It's not a thread-safe class.  The idea is to get a connection, use it, and close it in the narrowest scope possible.

Yes, you'll need a pool of them.  Every Java EE app server will have a JNDI pooling mechanism for you.  I wouldn't recommend one class for all queries, either.  Your chat ap

Your chat app ought to have a few sensible objects in its domain model.  I'd create data access objects for them as appropriate.  Keep the queries related to a particular domain model object in its DAO.

Answer (score 0):

is the info in this thread up-to-date? Googling brings up a lot of different things, as well as this - http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/connection_pooling_with_connectorj.html